# Pushwoosh multiple bundle ids on the same pushwoosh app

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

We've developed a flavor of our main app with a few UI alterations and when push notifications came to the table, the idea is to have both apps receive the same push notifs.

It appears like ( but never said explicitly ) that a Pushwoosh app can only receive one certificate essentially only covering one bundle id. The questions are:

A) Is this right to assume this? Is there any workaround about this or is the only way forward to make a new Pushwoosh app

B) If A new Pushwoosh app is the only solution, does anybody know where i can find information about the pricing? Our current plan is only allowing for two apps and their pricing page doesnt say anything about this.. https://www.pushwoosh.com/pricing/

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PushWoosh utilizes the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) and [Google FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) - which are tied to your iOS and Android apps respectively. It is not possible for these certificates/configurations to use multiple applications, and PushWoosh doesn't support multi-app setups.

I've spoken with Pushwoosh support about a similar matter. 
They are very prompt and accommodating in their replies - they certainly will do their best to provide you with a solution that is best suited to your needs.

Their pricing information can be found [here](https://www.pushwoosh.com/pricing/), though in my experience working with Pushwoosh, they are very open to providing you a custom plan.

As for a recommendation about sending a push notification to two(or multiple) different PushWoosh apps...

- Create some custom API that you POST your notification to *this* address, rather than directly to PushWoosh.
- Set up your API so that it can retrieve the same details as you expect a push notification to display, and configure it that when a request is recieved, forward the POST to the additional PushWoosh apps.

I'm currently using a similar setup that requires multiple push notifications to be sent from one event, and the custom API(hosted with Microsoft Azure) greatly simplifies this on the front end. The same concept would apply in this case, only it would send the notification to the different PushWoosh apps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. However i apologise but i need to push back a bit on the following front. The pricing information here is the same as i posted and it doesnt say anything at all about how to add more apps, it only speaks about devices. In our pushwoosh dashboard the option to create a new app is grayed out and says that we need to upgrade our plan.. This is vague and not reflected anywhere in their pricing page. As for the API solution i too was afraid this might be the only way forward..

Comment: I don't think an API is necesarilly a bad thing, it can be a hassle to set up, but can be very powerful if used correctly. 

Yes, our troubles with pushwoosh pricing were to do with increasing the number of tags (or filters?) available, which is very vague on their pricing page as well. 

I emailled pushwoosh support and they were very responsive and helpful providing new pricing information, which was tailored as an 'upgrade pack' to our current plan (_vastly_ cheaper than the next plan up.)

Good luck!

Comment: i ll have to contact them too i suppose. an API isnt a bad thing, by all means. But not being able to add another pushwoosh app identifier because of some vague restriction that is not mentioned anywhere in the pricing is pretty... lame in lack of a better word

Comment: I'd have to agree with you there. There's definitely not a lot of information on pricing and setup readily available.